# Can two celery applications be interdependent? or two tasks of one application be interdependent?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, message-queue, distributed-computing

My workflow is as follows, i am using Celery with rabbitMQ

step 1. A large file is broken into multiple parts(let's say 4), and put into MQ,

step 2. some workers(let's say 2) will process those files and store somewhere.

now, my question is , i have another task to complete, and that is joining those files, which ofcourse is a synchronous task, i.e. all parts of file should have been processed, so, what do I do through CELERY to make joining task dependent on step 2.

Do i create a separate application to join files, which somehow could receive status of these workers, whether they have finished processing those files.

or put joining of files as a task in MQ, which again could (block waiting) assure that, all parts are processed, n then join files, (This again can be done by any worker)

which approach is achievable? 
to make these two tasks interdependent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes two celery applications/tasks can be interdependent.

To achieve you goal I would use the celery canvas:
http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html
and more precisly 'chords'

> A chord is a task that only executes after all of the tasks in a group have finished
>   executing.

```
from celery import chord

@task
def process_parts(part):
    pass

@task
def join_parts(parts)
    pass

def split_file(f)
    return file_parts_array

def process_file(f):
    process_parts = [process_part.s(x) for x in split_file(f)]
    join_parts = join_files.s()
    result = chord(process_parts)(join_parts)
    return result
```

You map the task join_parts to a specific queue so only the workers on the storage machine consume the join_files tasks.